# Android. Как запретить пересоздавать Activity при смене ночной/дневной темы?

Tags: android, android-fragment

На устройстве можно через шторку менять тему на ночную/дневную. И при смене темы мое приложение закрывается с ошибкой, связанной с пересозданием Activity и DialogFragment.

Лог прилагаю:

```
2022-03-01 02:00:46.586 16041-16041/com.p.test.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.p.test.app, PID: 16041
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.p.test.app/com.p.test.app.ui.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.p.test.app.ui.dialogs.ActivityDialogFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4060)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:6253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:6144)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.p.test.app.ui.dialogs.ActivityDialogFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:628)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2728)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:198)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$2.onContextAvailable(FragmentActivity.java:149)
        at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:322)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:273)
        at com.p.test.app.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8214)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8202)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4033)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:6253) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:6144) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2613) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.p.test.app.ui.dialogs.ActivityDialogFragment.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2728) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:198) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$2.onContextAvailable(FragmentActivity.java:149)
```

Мне нужно как то запретить это "пересоздание", или не использовать фрагменты?

Upd: эта ошибка возникает если в момент переключения темы был открыт диалог `DialogFragment`

Код класса ActivityDialogFragment:

```
open class ActivityDialogFragment(val activity: Activity) : DialogFragment()  {
    var rootView: FrameLayout? = null
    var dialogContentView: ViewGroup? = null

    init {
        rootView = FrameLayout(activity)
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.app_dialog, null)
        dialogContentView = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogContent)
        rootView!!.addView(view)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity(), R.style.FullScreen)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.window!!.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.ActivityDialogFragment_Default_Animation

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val window = dialog!!.window!!

        window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        window.setDimAmount(0.00f)
        window.setLayout(
            activity.window.decorView.width,
            activity.window.decorView.height)
        rootView!!.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            activity.window.decorView.width,
            activity.window.decorView.height)
        dialog!!.setContentView(rootView!!)
        rootView!!.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
    open fun setContent(content: View){
        dialogContentView?.addView(content)
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.p.test.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.WelcomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Если запретить пересоздавать - тема будет меняться только после пересоздания активити иными средствами, что так же вызовет тот же краш да ещё и затруднит смену темы. Не использовать фрагменты - также не может считаться разумным решением. Скорее всего у вас ошибка в коде класса ActivityDialogFragment. Скорее всего вы в нём свой собственный конструктор создали. По идее, если его удалить - проблема исчезнет. Коли нет - покажите код ActivityDialogFragment

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне ночная тема вообще не нужна, я даже выбрал только светлую тему 'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar', но все равно приложение реагирует на смену системной темы. Код диалога сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Манифест добавьте

Comment: @arty-morris добавил

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я зачем то сделал конструктор принимающий `Activity`, хотя `DialogFragment` и так должен привязываться к `Activity` при вызове `show`. Попробую переделать и скажу помогло ли. Спасибо)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы были правы! Убрал конструктор, и ошибка исчезла. Только теперь после пересоздания не восстанавливается открытый диалог, но это мелочь. И все же, есть ли способ полностью игнорировать изменение темы?

Comment: Поменяйте тему в манифесте, на light, должно исчезнуть

Comment: Вообще, диалог должен по дефолту пересоздаваться. Возможная причина не пересоздания может быть в коде активити, например там, где вы диалог показываете. Также меня смущает то, что вы вьюху диалога инциализируете в блоке инициализации фрагмента. В этом особого смысла нет, попробуйте перенести этот код в onCreateDialog или в onStart. А ещё более вероятно то, что диалог у вас на самом деле отображается, но, т.к. фон у него прозрачный и вы не вызвали из активити, после пересоздания оной метод setContent - вы ничего не видите, т.к. видеть нечего. Проверьте это убрав установку прозрачности фону.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо! Позже попробую разобраться как правильно работать с фрагментами и с диалогами. Но сейчас мне нужно просто игнорировать изменение ночной/дневной темы, так как жалуются пользователи, у которых стоит автоматическая смена ночной темы. И я нашел как это сделать. Добавил ответ с решением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы приложение игнорировало изменение ночной/дневной темы, нужно добавить в манифест активити `android:configChanges="uiMode"`